# replace null values with double quotes globally in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

while running the query from SQL developer i am getting double quotes in place of null values.

Client demands for the same result as of sql developer hence after doing all formatting not getting double quotes in place of null in output for oracle 19C DB in AWS RDS.

Kindly suggest any way we can define it for all null values with single query.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how you are running queries and extracting the results. I'd guess you're running a query with `/*csv*/` or `set sqlformat csv`? What do you mean by "client demands for the same result" - the same as what, running the same query through a different client/tool/application?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with an example of your query that generates that output.